# Silently handle firebase data notification by app only

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my flutter android app i want firebase data notification only to be handled by app silently.
If app is running it will handle data otherwise no notification must be shown.
How can i achieve this

Too much notification might be annoying

here is my code

```dart
    final FirebaseMessaging fbMessaging = new FirebaseMessaging();

    @override
    Future<void> asyncInitStart( BuildContext context ) async
    {
        fbMessaging.subscribeToTopic('chat');
        fbMessaging.configure( onMessage: collectFirebaseMsg );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a message that always triggers your code, and never shows a notification on its own, send a `data` message without a `notification` property.

For more on this, see the [documentation on message types](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options).